# Some Apps not Installing on CM 10.1

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, installation

I've recently installed CM 10.1 on my Xperia ZL. Everything seems to be working fine except that i can't installed some apps on it. For example Contact+ doesn't install on it and gives the following message after trying to install it from the market:

"App not Installed"

Any help regarding this problem is appreciated.

Comment: When you bought your phone, did it have Contact+ on it or did you have to install it from Google Play store?

Comment: It didn't have Contact+. However it seems the problem was from Contact+ itself. I was able to install it after 3 or 4 versions.